# Google Reverse Geocode Multiple Coordinates with one API call?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I've read that this Reverse Geocode Lookup:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
Only works with one set of coordinates at a time.

Does Google have a solution or API that allows batch processing of Reverse Geocode Lookups?

If Google does not offer this, are there 3rd party options that are comparable?

I have thousands of coordinates to parse in a short amount of time that cannot be cached in a local database, and I don't want my application to make that many HTTP requests or hit any Query Limits imposed by Google looking up one point at a time.

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: Maybe this [Batch Geocoder API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/data-input.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment left by [Michael P. Bazos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3120193/michael-p-bazos), led me to the best solution, [HERE Batch Reverse Geocoding](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/batch_geocoding/batch-reverse-geocode-locations).  This is the example offered in their documentation:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: *' \
  -d 'recId|prox
0001|52.505308,13.327739,250
0002|49.917257,8.486488,250
0003|51.119593,7.399356,250
0004|49.20012,8.12326,250
0005|51.116845,7.397318,250
0006|52.265938,7.976922,250
0007|48.143131,10.829233,250
0008|51.770237,7.442682,250
0009|51.511877,7.461382,250
0010|52.53,13.391389,250' \
  'http://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs?gen=8&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ&action=run&mailto=%3Cmy_email%3E&header=true&indelim=%7C&outdelim=%7C&outcols=displayLatitude%2CdisplayLongitude%2ClocationLabel%2ChouseNumber%2Cstreet%2Cdistrict%2Ccity%2CpostalCode%2Ccounty%2Cstate%2Ccountry&outputCombined=false&mode=retrieveAddresses'
```

Since Google does not offer a comparable service themselves, this is the best solution.